# PHP / MSQL : User Sign Up Page

Tags: php, mysql

Recently I have been creating an PHP / MySQL user sign up page, and I've run into a problem in which it's keep getting an error when I call for the function, it returns to me:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function signUp() in
>   /Users/Ronald/Desktop/PHP/Brighten/admin/signup-method.php on line 65"

I wonder why does that happen. I'm sure this question must have been answered at somewhere already but I'm not that great at searching for it, so thank you for paying attention and thanks in advance

Error message:
[image]

How it suppose to look like:
[image]

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'database_host';
$dbuser = 'database_user';
$dbpass = 'database_password';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbuser);
    if (!$conn){
        die('cannot connect to mysql');
    }


    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password'])){
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['cpassword'])){
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }


    function addUser(){
        $query = "INSERT INTO websiteusers (user,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')"; 
        $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); 
        if($data) { 
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank you, <strong>'.$_POST['name'].'</strong>! You are successfully registered</div>';
    }

    function signUp(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$username' AND pass = '$password'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                addUser();
            }else{
            die("   <div class='alert alert-warning'>
                        <strong>Warning!</strong> You're already an registered user!
                    </div>");
            }
        }        
    }




    if ($_POST["submit"]) {
        if (!$_POST['username']) {
            $error="<br />Please enter your name";
        }
        if (!$_POST['password']) {
            $error.="<br />Please enter your password";
        }
        if (!$_POST['email']) {
            $error.="<br />Please enter your email";
        }
        if ($password != $cpassword){
            $error.= "<br/> Please confirm password is the same";
        }   
        if ($error) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"> There were error(s)in your form: '.$error.'</div>';
        }
        signUp();
    }


  ?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Btw. You're code should give you a bunch of "Undefined variable" as well. You must pass the variables to your functions. When you define a variable outside a function (in the global scope), that variable isn't automatically available inside functions. They need to be passed as function arguments.

Comment: You're also mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. You open with `mysqli_connect()` and are using `mysql_query()` in your `addUser()` function. They are not interchangeable. Stick with `mysqli_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made a mistake in the add user function.
Two { are opened but just one } is closed. Thats why the signUp is undefined because it is now a part of the adduser function.

Answer (score -1):

parenthesis not closed in adduser just use following code

```
function addUser(){
    $query = "INSERT INTO websiteusers (user,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')"; 
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); 
    if($data) { 
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank you, <strong>'.$_POST['name'].'</strong>! You are successfully registered</div>';
}





function signUp(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$username' AND pass = '$password'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            addUser();
        }else{
        die("   <div class='alert alert-warning'>
                    <strong>Warning!</strong> You're already an registered user!
                </div>");
        }
    }
```